# How to pause recursive JavaScript function? Function uses setInterval() to delay each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

```
        function live() { 

            middleMan = setInterval(processGeneration, speed);
            if (!dead) {
                window.clearInterval(middleMan);
                live();
            }
        }
```

This code is intended to run function *processgeneration()* every *speed* miliseconds, until *dead* is true. When the code is run, it returns

```
error: too much recursion
```

to the console. I have ignored this because the code still works as intended (apparently). Now I want to add a pause function, like this:

```
                if (!pause) {
                    live();
                    console.log(g); //for debugging
                }
```

but it does not react to the value of pause being changed (toggled by button click). neither is the value of *g* returned to the console. How do I resolve this isse?

Comment: "I have ignored this". Wrong. If you try to add new stuff to wrong code all you get is more errors. Your `live()` function is calling itself indefinitely. You are checking for `dead` variable in `live()` and what about `processGeneration()`? And LBNL aren't you probably using `setInterval` where `setTimeout` should me used?

Comment: did you downvote my question because I informed you that "I have ignored this"? If so, I think it is unjustified because it relates to the problem itself, and not to how I communicated it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, sorry.

Comment: oh ok, nevermind then. Your comment was helpful btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  function live() { 
    if (dead) {
      clearInterval(middleMan);
      return;
    }
    // do something when alive
  } 
  var middleMan=setInterval(live,speed);
```

or

```
  function live() { 
    if (dead) {
      return;
    }
    // do something when alive
    setTimeout(live,speed);
  } 
  live();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have called `live()` function recursively, which is not stoped ever,  I think you want something like this, the `processgeneration()` is executing until dead is true.

```
var speed = 1000;
dead = false;

middleMan = setInterval(processGeneration, speed);
function live() { 
    if (dead) {
        alert('this will clear the set interval');
        window.clearInterval(middleMan);
    }
}

function processGeneration(){
    console.log("output ");
}

setTimeout(function(){
    dead = true; //put your condition here when your dead is true
    live();
}, 4000);

live();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e2kT9/)